# SSIS data flow task or store procedure?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2014

Which is the faster way to load data from a table in one server to another table present in a different server? Data flow task or a stored procedure in an Execute SQL Task? Say, the table has around 100 million records and has necessary indexing.

Where I work, stored procedures are used and I would like to better the execution time taken. I was just wondering whether changing it to DFT could make it any faster. And, in some cases there are a lot of JOINS involved.So, on a general aspect which can offer better performance (regardless of the table structure or execution plan)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SSIS is normally much better at handling movement of data across different servers. If you have to use a SP, then you must use openquery to get the best performance. Also dont do a Execute SQL task. You need a DFT.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Thomas